# Error in shiny prerendered runtime when introducing a selectInput()

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a functioning Shiny interactive document (.Rmd) file that works fine locally and on shinyapps.io. I am trying to prerender it using instructions here (http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny_prerendered.html) but am running into an unusual error when I introduce a selectInput().

**The error message I am getting is the following:**
[image]

Here's a mininal code block that produces the error.

(app.Rmd)

````
---
title: 'a title'
output: html_document
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r, context = 'setup', include=FALSE}
library(shiny)

```

```{r, context='render'}
selectInput('hello','Hi',choices=c('1','2'))
```

```{r, context='server'}

```
````

Here is my sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.6     digest_0.6.10   rprojroot_1.1   mime_0.5        R6_2.1.2        xtable_1.8-2    backports_1.0.3
[8] magrittr_1.5    evaluate_0.10   stringi_1.1.1   rmarkdown_1.3   tools_3.2.2     stringr_1.1.0   httpuv_1.3.3   
[15] yaml_2.1.13     htmltools_0.3.5 knitr_1.15.1
```

I've tried changing the encoding of my Rmd to UTF-8 with no luck. Changing the runtime to "shiny" (from "shiny_prerendered") seems to fix the problem. Is this a bug in the "shiny_prerendered" runtime or am I doing something wrong?